# How much storage capacity my dataset or table consume?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have multiple datasets, each with hundreds of tables in Google BigQuery. I'd like to remove some old, legacy data and I am looking for the most convenient way to know how much storage space my each dataset and table is occupying, so I could make educated decision on what datasets/tables I may remove.

I tried to use `bq` command-line tool but couldn't find a way to display table storage and entire dataset storage related information.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Rather than using the BigQuery API (`Tables: get` method specifically) and looking into `numBytes` in the response, I can suggest to use [BQdu or BigQuery Disk Usage](http://bqdu.info) web application. It will scan your project for datasets and tables and will display this nice visualization, mentioning how much storage each table (or entire dataset) is consuming.

[image]

Comment: The website bqdu.info is down

Answer (score 6):

You can access metadata about the tables in a dataset by using the **TABLES** meta-table. I.e., and example:

```
select * from [publicdata:samples.__TABLES__]
```

returns

```
project_id  dataset_id  table_id    creation_time   last_modified_time  row_count   size_bytes  type     
publicdata  samples github_nested   1348782587310   1348782587310   2541639     1694950811  1    
publicdata  samples github_timeline 1335915950690   1335915950690   6219749     3801936185  1    
publicdata  samples gsod            1335916040125   1440625349328   14420316    17290009238 1    
publicdata  samples natality        1335916045005   1440625330604   37826763    23562717384 1    
publicdata  samples shakespeare     1335916045099   1440625429551   164656      6432064         1    
publicdata  samples trigrams        1335916127449   1445684180324   68051509    277168458677    1    
publicdata  samples wikipedia       1335916132870   1445689914564   13797035    38324173849     1
```

More documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how to combine use of metadata (as in answer by @Moshapasumansky) with visualization (as in recommendation by @DoITInternational) and all without leaving BigQuery Web UI, *but you will need [BigQuery Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) Chrome Extension*

Assuming you have extension - Follow below steps:

Step 1 - `Run Query` against tables metadata in publicdata:samples dataset

```
SELECT 
  table_id,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP(creation_time/1000)) AS Created, 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP(last_modified_time/1000)) AS  Modified,
  row_count AS Rows,
  ROUND(size_bytes/POW(1024, 3)) AS GB
FROM [publicdata:samples.__TABLES__]
```

[image]

Step 2 - Move to `JSON` View

[image]

Step 3 - Expand Result Panel by Clicking on `+` Button
This is for two reasons:

- To bring to result panel up to 500 records (which should cover your case as you mentioned you have hundreds tables) at  a time vs. relatively limited amount of rows at a time that currently supported by native ui
- To release more real estate for chart

[image]

Step 4 - Close Query Editor (optional) – more real estate for chart

[image]

Step 5 - Click Show Pivot to bring Pivot/Chart Tool up with data from Result and than design your pivot chart the way you like (*as it is in below screenshot for example*)

[image]

It might be not the best way - but at least it allows you to do what you want here w/o leaving web ui. In some cases it can be a preferred option I think.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try that!